# DependencyProperty problem with Double and Single

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties

Silverligh 4, VS 2010.

Making a Custom Control. (Non just UserControl, but  public class HandPart : Control, and a template in \themes)

Then I creating a new DependencyProperty with a helper snippet:

```
#region SomeDouble (DependencyProperty)

/// <summary>
/// A description of the property.
/// </summary>
public Double SomeDouble
{
    get { return (Double)GetValue(SomeDoubleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SomeDoubleProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeDoubleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SomeDouble", typeof(Double), typeof(HandPart),
      new PropertyMetadata(0));

#endregion
```

As a result solution is compiling with out any errors and messages but it not starting up.
When I creating DependencyProperty with, fore example, Int type insted Double or Single, it's working OK.

What is the problem, (feature?) with float? Why I can't create DP with a floats types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `0` argument that you're passing to the `PropertyMetadata` constructor will be interpreted as an `int` rather than a `double`. Try passing `0.0` instead:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeDoubleProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SomeDouble", typeof(Double),
        typeof(HandPart), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));
```